# WebMock stopping selenium from deleting session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara, webmock

#### System

- Ruby v2.6
- WebMock gem v3.18.1
- Selenium Webdriver gem v4.1.0
- RSpec gem v3.11.0
- Capybara gem v3.36.0

#### Summary

Whilst successfully running a suite of tests on GitLab CI[1], WebMock intercepts a request from Capybara's Selenium driver to delete a session[2].

> 743 examples, 0 failures, 30 pending
>
> /builds/abelsoninfo/aws/pips/pips-console/vendor/ruby/ruby/2.6.0/gems/webmock-3.18.1/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:104:in
> `request': Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request:
> DELETE
> http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub/session/0146cfc5158d585f445cfcdbda289733

Although the error appears after the tests have run I wonder if it occurs whilst the specs are running? This is due to seeing newlines appearing in the RSpec output:

> .......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................**...***............
> *...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................
> *...........................................................................................................................................................................**.**.........**...****...*........................................***.*********

In **spec/support/capybara.rb** I have allowed connections to any URL with **selenium**, or **session** in it:

```rb
selenium_session_requests = %r{/((__.+__)|(hub/session.*))$}
allowed_connections = [
  '0.0.0.0', '127.0.0.1', 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com',
  'localhost', /selenium/, selenium_session_requests
].freeze

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    WebMock.enable!
  end

  config.after(:suite) do
    WebMock.disable!
  end

  Capybara.app_host = "http://#{Capybara.server_host}:#{Capybara.server_port}"

  Capybara.javascript_driver = ENV.fetch('CAPYBARA_JAVASCRIPT_DRIVER', :chrome_headless).to_sym

  WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow: allowed_connections, net_http_connect_on_start: allowed_connections)
end
```

I have previously confirmed in the `before(:suite)` block that a session URL, such as **http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub/session/0146cfc5158d585f445cfcdbda289733** would be allowed by WebMock.

Per the suggestion in [2] I stubbed the request - though I don't believe this is desired behaviour - but that still caused the same error.

#### Observed behaviour

WebMock does not allow the Selenium driver to exit the browser.

#### Desired behaviour

The browser is closed, and no errors are raised.

**[1]** In `.gitlab-ci.yml` I have a docker service to enable the use of Selenium:

```
image: ruby:2.6
  services:
    - postgres:10.1
    - selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    - redis:latest
```

The URL for that service is exposed to my specs via an environment variable:

```
- export SELENIUM_REMOTE_URL="http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub"
```

**[2]** Here is the full output from the WebMock error:

> /builds/abelsoninfo/aws/pips/pips-console/vendor/ruby/ruby/2.6.0/gems/webmock-3.18.1/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:104:in
> `request': Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: DELETE http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub/session/0146cfc5158d585f445cfcdbda289733 with headers {'Accept'=>'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'User-Agent'=>'selenium/4.1.0 (ruby linux)'} (WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError) You can stub this request with the following snippet: stub_request(:delete, "http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub/session/0146cfc5158d585f445cfcdbda289733"). with( headers: {      'Accept'=>'application/json',       'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3',       'Content-Type'=>'application/json; charset=UTF-8',      'User-Agent'=>'selenium/4.1.0 (ruby linux)' }).   to_return(status: 200, body: "", headers: {}) ============================================================  from /builds/abelsoninfo/aws/pips/pips-console/vendor/ruby/ruby/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:124:in` response_for'    from
> /builds/abelsoninfo/aws/pips/pips-console/vendor/ruby/ruby/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:77:in
> `request'     from /builds/abelsoninfo/aws/pips/pips-console/vendor/ruby/ruby/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in` call'    from
> /builds/abelsoninfo/aws/pips/pips-console/vendor/ruby/ruby/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:588:in
> `execute'     from /builds/abelsoninfo/aws/pips/pips-console/vendor/ruby/ruby/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:188:in` quit'    from
> /builds/abelsoninfo/aws/pips/pips-console/vendor/ruby/ruby/2.6.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.1.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:181:in
> `quit'    from /builds/abelsoninfo/aws/pips/pips-console/vendor/ruby/ruby/2.6.0/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:293:in` quit'    from
> /builds/abelsoninfo/aws/pips/pips-console/vendor/ruby/ruby/2.6.0/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:512:in
> `block in setup_exit_handler'

Comment: I've got the same problem using `WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)`